# Nifi throwing None of the fields in the record map to the columns defined by [table name]

Tags: apache-nifi, cloudera

Am trying execute a sql query on oracle database and inserting the result into another table, for my trial am just performing a simple query as

```
SELECT 1 AS count 
  FROM dual
```

and trying to insert that into a single column table which has the name `COUNT`.
The content of the record on Nifi seems to be as follows

```json
[
 { 
   "COUNT" : "1" 
 }
]
```

but the logs keeps throwing the error

> ```java
> due to java.sql.SQLDataException: 
> None of the fields in the record map to the columns defined by 
> the schema_name.table_name table:
> ```

any ideas ?

[image]

Comment: "The content of the record on Nifi seems to be as follow [{"COUNT":"1"}]" , can you be sure by looking at the flowfile content in queue please ?

Comment: yes, I got that from the flowFile content

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you get that same error message if your table name doesn't match. The `Translate Field Names` property only translates the fields (columns), not the table name. Try specifying the schema/table in uppercase to match what Oracle is expecting.

Comment: that was correct... I had to capitalize the schema name in order to get it to work